# Xamarin.iOS unknown crash when app starts

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I have a weird behavior with an iOS app I'm working on.

When I build my app in Release mode in Visual Studio, it works fine, deploys and runs OK on my iPhone.

Then I do the same thing using XBuild via command line, create the .ipa, deploy it to the same phone, and I get a crash right after the system splashscreen.
The same command line, executed on another mac, provides an .ipa that does not crash.

And the crash stacktrace provided by XCode does not help much:

```
Date/Time:           2017-06-19 11:22:01.279 +0200
Launch Time:         2017-06-19 11:21:59.536 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_907  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195e37270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ed516c pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000195daeb14 abort + 108
3   MyApp                       0x0000000101f9df20 mono_handle_native_crash (mini-exceptions.c:2615)
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000195ecc958 _sigtramp + 64
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ed516c pthread_kill + 108
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000195daeb14 abort + 108
7   MyApp                       0x00000001020b29c0 mono_log_write_asl (mono-log-darwin.c:40)
8   MyApp                       0x00000001020c6188 monoeg_g_log (goutput.c:125)
9   MyApp                       0x0000000101f68078 load_aot_module (aot-runtime.c:2060)
10  MyApp                       0x0000000101fbd2fc mono_assembly_load_from_full (assembly.c:2099)
11  MyApp                       0x0000000101fbce5c mono_assembly_open_a_lot (assembly.c:1779)
12  MyApp                       0x00000001020d3168 assembly_preload_hook(_MonoAssemblyName*, char**, void*) (monotouch-main.m:137)
13  MyApp                       0x0000000101fbef24 mono_assembly_load_corlib (assembly.c:1478)
14  MyApp                       0x0000000101fdf248 mono_init_internal (domain.c:556)
15  MyApp                       0x0000000101faa7e8 mini_init (mini-runtime.c:3680)
16  MyApp                       0x00000001020d2e84 xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:420)
17  MyApp                       0x0000000101e29b78 main (main.m:245)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000195d1ea04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195e1cc24 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195d01e6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195cf3998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2 name:  SGen worker
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195e37078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ed2f28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   MyApp                       0x00000001020a6228 thread_func (mono-os-mutex.h:146)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ed3dc4 _pthread_body + 160
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ed3d20 _pthread_start + 156
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195ed0ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000036
    x4: 0x000000016fd10c18   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000125d18000  x11: 0x0000000000000fff
   x12: 0x0000000000000036  x13: 0x0000000125d14000  x14: 0x0000000000003fff  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000010  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000199d10310  x21: 0x0000000102170a64  x22: 0x0000000102170b16  x23: 0x000000016fd11678
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000012680d080  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000001023c70b0
   x28: 0x00000001023c4c20  fp: 0x000000016fd11610   lr: 0x0000000195ed5170
    sp: 0x000000016fd115f0   pc: 0x0000000195e37270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Any ideas, leads, possible origin would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Delete bin and obj folder in your project folder and clean it then try to build it again and make sure to select proper certificates for release mode.

Comment: My release mode works fine when executed from Visual Studio for mac. I only get the issue when packaging the app from a script ... that also works fine when executed from another machine

Comment: My god, manually deleting bin and obj folders for every projet of my solution seems to work ???
I'm used to doing that, but still ...